# How to upload multiple images and store their name in database with phalcon?

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon

I have created a form for users can upload multiple images,and move uploaded images to 'Upload' folder and store their names in database. This is my code

```
class ImageController extends Controller
{

    public function imageAction()
    {
       // $mgr_com = new Commons();

        if ($this->request->hasFiles() == true) {
            $uploads = $this->request->getUploadedFiles();
            //print_r($uploads);
            $isUploaded = false;
            foreach ($uploads as $upload) {
                $mgr_com = new Commons();
                $path = strtolower($upload->getname());
                //$path = 'temp / ' . md5(uniqid(rand(), true)) . ' - ' . strtolower($upload->getname());
                //print_r($path);
                $sql= "call img('$path')";
                $results = $mgr_com->getReadConnection()->query($sql);
                ($upload->moveTo($path)) ? $isUploaded = true : $isUploaded = false;

            }

            ($isUploaded) ? die("Files successfully uploaded.") : die("Some error ocurred.");
        } /*else {

            die("You must choose at least one file to send. Please try again.");
        }*/
    }
}
```

After upload all images successfully move to 'Uploads' folder but, in database it store only one image name. So how to store all images name in database? Please help me and thanks you for help.

This is my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#imageupload").change(function () {
        if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
            var dvPreview = $("#preview-image");
            dvPreview.html("");
            var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.jpg|.jpeg|.gif|.png|.bmp)$/;
            $($(this)[0].files).each(function () {
                var file = $(this);
                if (regex.test(file[0].name.toLowerCase())) {
                    var file_data = $('#imageupload').prop('files')[0];
                    var form_data = new FormData();
                    form_data.append('file', file_data);
                    for (var i = 0; i < file_data.length; i++) {
                        form_data.append("UploadedImage" + i, file_data[i]);
                    }
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'/image/image',
                        method: "POST",
                        data: form_data,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        multiple: true,
                        success: function(response){
                            var result= $.parseJSON(response);
                            if(result.success){
                                $("#image1").html("<img  src=http://localhost/template/fileupload/"+result.userObj.file+">");

                            }else{
                                $("#error").show().html(result.message);
                            }
                        }

                    });
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        var img = $("<img />");
                        img.attr("style", "height:100px;width: 100px");
                        img.attr("src", e.target.result);
                        dvPreview.append(img);
                    }
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file[0]);
                } else {
                    alert(file[0].name + " is not a valid image file.");
                    dvPreview.html("");
                    return false;
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert("This browser does not support HTML5 FileReader.");
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: can you share sample data of `FILES`

Comment: what do you mean sample data , As I am uploading image file

Comment: format `file[0]['name']`, `file[1]['name']` such like that

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: I dont know Phalcon. But normally you can have user_images as one more table where you can have id, image_name, userid and other respective columns as per your needs. And thus you can handle multiple uploads

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following :

```
$results = new Resultset(null,
                         $mgr_com,
                         $mgr_com->getReadConnection()->query($sql));
```

See [PHQL documentation](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/db-phql#raw-sql)